# Apply that returns dataframe

Tags: pandas-apply

I have one dataframe that has an index of ID's, and a function that takes an ID and returns some data regarding that ID (1 row). I want to create another dataframe with the same ID's as the index, but the columns are the columns and values that are gathered from my function. I'm trying to use apply but I'm not sure how to do it.

For example,

```
def f(id):
    does stuff
    return id_df

new_df = pd.DataFrame(index = original_df.index)

new_df.apply(lambda x: f(x.name).values, axis = 1)
```

Doing this gives me something that looks like:

```
id1       [[data...
id2       [[data...
id3       [[data...
id4       [[data...
id5       [[data...
```

All the data shows up as one column. How can I make it so that the columns of the output function fill out columns of the new_df?

Answer (score 0):

You should call .apply() on the old dataframe and return the result to the column of the new dataframe, as follows:

```
new_df['colA'] = old_df.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

If you are trying to write multiple values to multiple columns, see: [Writing the output of df.apply() to multiple columns at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667572/writing-the-output-of-df-apply-to-multiple-columns-at-once)

Take note of the following:

- when calling apply, only use the function name as the first argument. Lambda is not needed.
- when using axis = 1, your function gets passed the full row. You need to identify the relevant column of the row in your function:

```
def f(row):
    id = row['ID']
    return stuff(id)
```

Comment: Thank you - but I need to do this for many multiple columns and the answer only deals with two done manually. Any ideas on how to put the two concepts together? Thanks again!